# Как можно реализовать этот вариант с использованием ACF на WordPress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, acf

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать такой пример используюя ACF на Wordpress.
Я этот вариант наверстал и реализовал с помощью jQuery-ui-tabs но как посадить на WP с помощью ACF пока не могу понять, подскажите пожалуйста.
Нет принципиальной разницы слайдером или табами, желательно вариант который будет проще реализовать и удобнее использовать с админки.
Спасибо !
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(function () {
  $("#tabs").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
  $("#tabs li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");
  $("#tabs").tabs({
    active: 0,
  });
});
```

```css
.tabs__descr {
  background-color: #003333;
}


.ui-tabs-vertical {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 27%;
  flex: 0 1 27%;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 95%;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li {
  position: relative;
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
  border-right-width: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 -1px 0.2em 0;
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: -10px;
  background-color: #003333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 9px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active:before {
  width: 104px;
  height: 104px;
  left: -48px;
  border: 12px solid #fff;
  background-image: url(../img/svg/ichtab.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: #33cccc;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 33px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0 15% 0 65px;
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 0.1em;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a {
  color: #33cccc;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.ui-tabs-panel.ui-corner-bottom.ui-widget-content:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border: 40px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 0 0 -150px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 73%;
  flex: 0 1 73%;
  padding: 70px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel p {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  color: #003333;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.tab__description__bottom {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.tab__description__bottom p {
  padding-left: 100px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.tab__description__bottom p:first-child {
  background-image: url(../img/svg/ab-i1.svg);
}

.tab__description__bottom p:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(../img/svg/ab-i2.svg);
}

.tab__description__bottom p:last-child {
  background-image: url(../img/svg/ab-i1.svg);
}

.tab__button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -29px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -105px;
}

.tab__button .button {
  background-color: #33cccc;
  color: #fff;
}

.tab__button .button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #003333;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<section class="tabs__descr">
        <div class="container">
          <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#tabs-1">Citizenship of Ukraine</a></li>
              <li><a href="#tabs-2">Temporary residence permit</a></li>
              <li><a href="#tabs-3">Permanent residence permit</a></li>
              <li><a href="#tabs-4">Invitation to Ukraine</a></li>
              <li><a href="#tabs-5">Registration in Kiev</a></li>
              <li><a href="#tabs-6">Extension of the period of stay</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
              <h2>Temporary residence permit</h2>
              <p>
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5
                second intervals.
              </p>
              <p>
                At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page.
              </p>
              <p>
                Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second intervals. At
                the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. At the
                bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. Picture
                with a title and a button to go to the corresponding page.
                Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second intervals. At
                the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. At the
                bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. Picture
                with a title and a button to go to the corresponding page.
              </p>
              <p>
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5
                second intervals.
              </p>
              <div class="about__icons tab__description__bottom">
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="tab__button">
                <a href="#" class="button">contact</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
              <h2>2Temporary residence permit</h2>
              <p>
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5
                second intervals.
              </p>
              <p>
                At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page.
              </p>
              <p>
                Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second intervals. At
                the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. At the
                bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. Picture
                with a title and a button to go to the corresponding page.
                Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second intervals. At
                the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. At the
                bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. Picture
                with a title and a button to go to the corresponding page.
              </p>
              <p>
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5
                second intervals.
              </p>
              <div class="about__icons tab__description__bottom">
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="tab__button">
                <a href="#" class="button">contact</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-3">
              <h2>1Temporary residence permit</h2>
              <p>
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5
                second intervals.
              </p>
              <p>
                At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page.
              </p>
              <p>
                Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second intervals. At
                the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. At the
                bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. Picture
                with a title and a button to go to the corresponding page.
                Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second intervals. At
                the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. At the
                bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. Picture
                with a title and a button to go to the corresponding page.
              </p>
              <p>
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5
                second intervals.
              </p>
              <div class="about__icons tab__description__bottom">
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="tab__button">
                <a href="#" class="button">contact</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-4">
              <h2>1Temporary residence permit</h2>
              <p>
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5
                second intervals.
              </p>
              <p>
                At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page.
              </p>
              <p>
                Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second intervals. At
                the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. At the
                bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. Picture
                with a title and a button to go to the corresponding page.
                Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second intervals. At
                the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. At the
                bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. Picture
                with a title and a button to go to the corresponding page.
              </p>
              <p>
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5
                second intervals.
              </p>
              <div class="about__icons tab__description__bottom">
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="tab__button">
                <a href="#" class="button">contact</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-5">
              <h2>1Temporary residence permit</h2>
              <p>
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5
                second intervals.
              </p>
              <p>
                At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page.
              </p>
              <p>
                Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second intervals. At
                the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. At the
                bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. Picture
                with a title and a button to go to the corresponding page.
                Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second intervals. At
                the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. At the
                bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. Picture
                with a title and a button to go to the corresponding page.
              </p>
              <p>
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5
                second intervals.
              </p>
              <div class="about__icons tab__description__bottom">
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="tab__button">
                <a href="#" class="button">contact</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-6">
              <h2>1Temporary residence permit</h2>
              <p>
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5
                second intervals.
              </p>
              <p>
                At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. At the bottom of the slider are the slider control
                buttons. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page.
              </p>
              <p>
                Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second intervals. At
                the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. At the
                bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. Picture
                with a title and a button to go to the corresponding page.
                Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second intervals. At
                the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. At the
                bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons. Picture
                with a title and a button to go to the corresponding page.
              </p>
              <p>
                Picture with a title and a button to go to the corresponding
                page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5 second
                intervals. Picture with a title and a button to go to the
                corresponding page. Slider images automatically switch at 3-5
                second intervals.
              </p>
              <div class="about__icons tab__description__bottom">
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
                <p>
                  At the bottom of the slider are the slider control buttons.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="tab__button">
                <a href="#" class="button">contact</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[fidle](https://jsfiddle.net/banky/cmaqbvsy/1/)

Возможно есть способ который будет добавлять ссылку с id и соответственно id табу при клонирование поля?

Comment: а что повторителем не получилось?

Comment: получилось сделать горизонтальный слайд, ок.
вот, думаю, этот момент с боковым "меню" как сделать что бы он отображался на каждом слайде, создавать ещё кучу полей ?

Comment: можно же внутри повторителя ещё повторитель создать

Comment: я так пробовал впервые - скорее из за отсутствия опыта не получилось, но это же чудо нужно будет как-то связать с основным слайдером, что бы работало по типу пагинации, если кликнуть на пункт "меню" пролистывало к соответствующему.
Не подскажете как это сделать или может поделитесь сссылкой ?
если что уже использую на проекте slickslider, там есть вариант sync slider, я пытался, не получилось. наверное что-то сделал не так...

Comment: а при чем тут acf? тут уже js

Comment: нужна возможность редактировать поля из админки.

Comment: сформулируйте вопрос, чтоб было видно что делали и на каком моменте ступор возник

Comment: Дополнил вопрос фидлом, возможно есть способ который будет добавлять ссылку с id и соответственно id табу при клонирование поля?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это при помощи repeater поля. Все что вам нужно, просто прогнать цикл 2 раза, чтобы не заморачиваться особо и все. Будет что-то вроде:

```
<?php if ( have_rows( 'your_repeater' ) ) : ?>
    <section class="tabs__descr">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="tabs">
                <ul>
                    <?php while ( have_rows( 'your_repeater' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                        <?php // Тут просто текстовое поле заголовка + id таба если нужно, можно сделать отдельным полем и подставить его в href ?>
                        <?php // Учтите что the_row_index() было добавлено в ACF с версии 5.8.8 вроде как, если более ранняя версия, используйте echo get_row_index(); ?>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-<?php the_row_index(); ?>"><?php the_sub_field( 'title' ); ?></a></li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
                <?php while ( have_rows( 'your_repeater' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                    <?php // Тут просто WYSIWYG ?>
                    <div id="tabs-<?php the_row_index(); ?>">
                        <?php the_sub_field( 'text' ); ?>
                        <?php if ( get_sub_field( 'description' ) ) : ?>
                            <div class="about__icons tab__description__bottom">
                                <?php // Тоже просто WYSIWYG ?>
                                <?php the_sub_field( 'description' ); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php
                        // Relational -> Link
                        $button = get_sub_field( 'button' );

                        if ( $button ) : ?>
                            <div class="tab__button">
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $button['url'] ); ?>" target="<?php echo ( $button['target'] ) ?: '_self'; ?>" class="button"><?php echo esc_html( $button['title'] ); ?></a>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ, как опробую сразу отпишу